# Create pulseaudio socket at system startup in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, audio-streaming, pulseaudio

I'm running a docker container and I pass the pulse server environment variable to my container. The container is set to restart always policy. The container fails to run if the **"pulseaudio.socket"** is not present in the **/tmp** folder.

So to achieve my goal I added the command `"pactl load-module module-native-protocol-unix socket=/tmp/pulseaudio.socket"` to startup applications[the GUI program which is accessed by searcing startup programs]. This command creates a **pulseaudio.socket** file in the **/tmp** folder

This method works most of the time if the **pulseaudio.socket** file is created before docker starts the container. If docker starts the container before the **pulseaudio.socket** is created, the container fails to start.

To make sure the pulseaudio.socket is always created before docker starts the container I added the code `"pactl load-module module-native-protocol-unix socket=/tmp/pulseaudio.socket"` to **/etc/rc.local** and also tried to add it to **init.d**.

But adding the code to **/etc/rc.local** or **init.d** creates a **pulse-PKdhtXMmr18n** folder in the **/tmp** folder instead of the file **pulseaudio.socket**

How do I make sure that instead of **pulse-PKdhtXMmr18n** , file called **pulseaudio.socket** is always created ?

My main objective is to create **/tmp/pulseaudio.socket** file before docker starts or before docker tries to start a container with restart policy.

> Or is there any way such that the docker service first checks if the
>   pulseaudio.socket file exists and if it exists then only start the
>   containers?

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue like this :

My container has got a node script which starts the application and this application needs pulseaudio to run properly. So here is my docker run command.
Notice the code in bold. That's what I modified.

Previous command

```bash
sudo docker run --pid=host -dit --restart unless-stopped --env PULSE_SERVER=unix:/tmp/pulseaudio.socket --env PULSE_COOKIE=/home/$USER/pulseaudio.cookie **--volume /tmp/pulseaudio.socket:/tmp/pulseaudio.socket** --volume /home/$USER/pulseaudio.client.conf:/etc/pulse/client.conf --user $(id -u):$(id -g) --privileged --net=host ubuntu bash -c "**node service.js** && tail -F anything"
```

Current command

```bash
sudo docker run --pid=host -dit --restart unless-stopped --env PULSE_SERVER=unix:/tmp/pulseaudio.socket --env PULSE_COOKIE=/home/$USER/pulseaudio.cookie **--volume /tmp:/tmp** --volume /home/$USER/pulseaudio.client.conf:/etc/pulse/client.conf --user $(id -u):$(id -g) --privileged --net=host ubuntu bash -c "**sh checksocket.sh** && tail -F anything"
```

In the previous command , the container used to start only if there was a `pulseaudio.socket` file in the /tmp folder of host.

Now the current working command mounts **`--volume /tmp:/tmp`** instead of **`--volume /tmp/pulseaudio.socket:/tmp/pulseaudio.socket`**

and **`sh checksocket.sh`** command executes the `checksocket.sh` file that I created inside the container.

Here is the code of my checksocket.sh file :

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while sleep 0.5;
do if [ -e /tmp/pulseaudio.socket ]
  then
    value="node service.js"
    exec $value
    break
  fi
done
```

This shell script keeps checking for the `pulseaudio.socket` file in the mounted `/tmp` folder and if it exists then only it starts my node service.

In this way my container always starts whenever I reboot my machine and the node service starts once the shell script detect a pulseaudio.socket in the `/tmp` folder.

I hope this helps someone who are trying to use pulseaudio with docker for the purpose of sound multiplexing or to avoid “device or resource busy” error(device or resource busy error comes when you use docker with alsa as alsa directly captures the sound card) on the host machine. Let me know if anybody needs more help